PyCharm says "invalid python interpreter" about the venv I used (after Ubuntu upgrade)
After upgrading Ubuntu, PyCharm says this:
(How can I make that venv work on newer Ubuntu? - I'd rather keep all installed packages in that venv)


If you upgraded and your system has a new Python version then you need to rebuild your venv.
